# ¿De donde saca la variable "z" los valores de la array "i"?

Tags: java, array

No logro identificar como hace la variable `z` para saber cuales son los números guardados en la array para luego trabajar con ellos, ya que se almacenan en la variable `i`, pero no veo como `z` sabe cuales son:

El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:
En este ejercicio se pide al usuario que introduzca 10 números enteros por consola. Los números
introducidos se almacenarán en un array. El programa imprime en consola cuántos números
negativos, positivos y valores 0 hay en el array.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    int media = 0;
    
    int pares = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Introduce 10 números enteros: ");
    
    int numeros [] = new int [10];
    
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        
        numeros [i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
        
    for (int z=0; z<10 ;z++) {
        if (z % 2 == 0 && z!=0) {
            pares++;
            media=media+numeros[z];
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Por favor aclara qué es lo que quieres lograr con ese código. Por suerte Marce adivinó bien, pero la respuesta queda en el aire sin contexto. Más cuando pase el tiempo y alguien se pregunte cómo es que la respuesta te fue útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, lo que pasa es que el código presentado es erróneo, no hace lo que se espera.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
double media = 0;
int pares = 0;
int cantidad = 5;
int numeros[] = new int[ cantidad ];

System.out.println( "Introduce " + cantidad + " números enteros: " );

for( int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++ ) {

      // en cada iteración, inicializamos una posición del array, con el valor ingresado.  
   numeros[ i ] = sc.nextInt();
}

for( int z = 0; z < cantidad; z++ ) {

      // sumamos los valores contenidos en el array
   media += numeros[ z ];

      // si el valor es par, aumentamos en "1" el valor de "par".  
   if( numeros[ z ] % 2 == 0 && numeros[ z ] != 0 ) {
      pares++;
   }
}
  // con "media / cantidad" obtenemos el promedio de los valores ingresados
System.out.println( "media = " + media / cantidad );
System.out.println( "pares = " + pares );
```

Como tu intuición te marcaba, la linea **if (z % 2 == 0 && z!=0) {**, es un absoluto sin sentido, ya que no toma los valores contenidos en el array, siempre te devolverá los mismos valores independientemente de los que ingreses.